# Making excel object in azure automation

Tags: azure, azure-automation

While making excel object in azure automation in powershell.

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

I am getting an error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

We have installed modules as importexcel,psexcel,read-excel in the modules but getting the same errors.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, none of those modules provide the COM class Excel.Application; you'd need to install Excel to get that.  And I believe you can only do this if you're running on a Hybrid Worker, as there's no way to access this in the cloud instance.